Pull notification not working in Cordova Angular app
pull-to-refresh functionality is working in the Angular web application, but when deployed as a Cordova application, it fails to function as intended.
Upon transitioning our Angular web application into a Cordova application for deployment on mobile platforms, we encountered a notable deviation in behavior. Despite implementing the same pull-to-refresh logic, the feature does not respond as expected when running the application on mobile devices.
this is my code
 <div (mousedown)="onTouchStart($event)" (touchstart)="onTouchStart($event)" 
     (mousemove)="onTouchMove($event)" (touchmove)="onTouchMove($event)" 
     (mouseup)="onTouchEnd()" (touchend)="onTouchEnd()">
     <app-pull-to-refresh></app-pull-to-refresh>
  <!-- Your content here (e.g., a list of items) -->
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

app.component.ts
 onTouchStart(event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) {
    // Capture the starting point of the touch/mouse event
    // You can customize the threshold to trigger the refresh
    if (event instanceof MouseEvent || (event instanceof TouchEvent && event.touches.length === 1)) {
      this.showPullToRefresh = true;
      this.pullText = 'Release to refresh';
    }
  }

  onTouchMove(event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) {
    // Calculate the distance and determine whether to show the pull-to-refresh indicator
    if (event instanceof MouseEvent || (event instanceof TouchEvent && event.touches.length === 1)) {
      const startY = event instanceof MouseEvent ? event.clientY : event.touches[0].clientY;
      const distanceY = startY - (event instanceof MouseEvent ? this.startY : this.touchStartY);

      if (distanceY >= 60) { // Adjust this threshold as needed
        this.showPullToRefresh = true;
        this.pullText = 'Release to refresh';
      } else {
        this.showPullToRefresh = false;
        this.pullText = 'Pull to refresh';
      }
    }
  }

  onTouchEnd() {
    if (this.showPullToRefresh) {
      // Perform data refresh here
      this.refreshData();

      this.showPullToRefresh = false;
      this.pullText = 'Pull to refresh';
    }
  }

pull-to-refresh.component.html
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%">
  <div
    style="margin-left: -35px"
    [style.transform]="positionTranslate3d$ | async"
  >
    <svg
      width="70px"
      height="70"
      [style.transform]="rotateTransform$ | async"
      [style.opacity]="opacity$ | async"
    >
      <!-- via: https://gist.github.com/redblobgames/6851dc787241e390c241cd9484b16e4d -->
      <filter id="dropShadow" height="130%">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" />
        <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur" />
        <feComponentTransfer>
          <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.5" />
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <feMerge>
          <feMergeNode />
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        </feMerge>
      </filter>
      <circle
        cy="35"
        cx="35"
        r="30"
        fill="white"
        style="filter:url(#dropShadow)"
      ></circle>
      <!-- via: https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline -->
      <path
        transform="scale(2.0,2.0) translate(5.5,5.5)"
        fill="blue"
        d="M17.65 6.35C16.2 4.9 14.21 4 12 4c-4.42 0-7.99 3.58-7.99 8s3.57 8 7.99 8c3.73 0 6.84-2.55 7.73-6h-2.08c-.82 2.33-3.04 4-5.65 4-3.31 0-6-2.69-6-6s2.69-6 6-6c1.66 0 3.14.69 4.22 1.78L13 11h7V4l-2.35 2.35z"
      />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>


pull-to-refresh.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { concat, defer, fromEvent, Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';
import {
  filter,
  map,
  repeat,
  skipUntil,
  startWith,
  switchMap,
  take,
  takeUntil,
  tap
} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LoadNotifyService } from 'src/app/services/load-notify.service';
// import { LoadNotifyService } from '../services/load-notify.service';

const TOP_POSITION = 0; 

/**
 *
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pull-to-refresh',
  templateUrl: './pull-to-refresh.component.html'
})
export class PullToRefreshComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly pullDistance = window.innerHeight / 3; // 引っ張る距離
  private readonly touchstart$ = fromEvent<TouchEvent>(document, 'touchstart');
  private readonly touchend$ = fromEvent<TouchEvent>(document, 'touchend');
  private readonly touchmove$ = fromEvent<TouchEvent>(document, 'touchmove');

  private drag$ = this.touchstart$.pipe(
    switchMap(start => {
      let pos = TOP_POSITION;

      return concat(
        this.touchmove$.pipe(
          map(move => move.touches[0].pageY - start.touches[0].pageY),
          tap(p => (pos = p)),
          filter(p => p < this.pullDistance),
          takeUntil(this.touchend$)
        ),
        defer(() => this.tweenObservable(pos, TOP_POSITION, 500)) 
      );
    }),
    repeat()
  );

  private position$: Observable<number> = this.drag$.pipe(
    startWith(TOP_POSITION)
  );

  positionTranslate3d$: Observable<string> = this.position$.pipe(
    map(p => `translate3d(0, ${p - 70}px, 0)`)
  );

  rotateTransform$: Observable<string> = this.position$.pipe(
    map(p => `rotate(${(p / this.pullDistance) * 360}deg)`)
  );

  opacity$: Observable<number> = this.position$.pipe(
    map(p => p / this.pullDistance)
  );

  constructor(private loadNotifyService: LoadNotifyService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.touchstart$
      .pipe(
        switchMap(start => {
          return this.touchend$.pipe(
            map(x => x.changedTouches[0].pageY - start.touches[0].pageY)
          );
        }),
        filter(p => p >= this.pullDistance)
      )
      .subscribe(() => this.loadNotifyService.notify());
  }

  private tweenObservable(start:any, end:any, time:any) {
    const emissions = time / 10;
    const step = (start - end) / emissions;

    return timer(0, 10).pipe(
      map(x => start - step * (x + 1)),
      take(emissions)
    );
  }
}`
`

